# Running selenium with Maven and get title not being asserted

Tags: java, maven, junit, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

here is the code i am using

```
public void SearchFor(final String searchKeyword)
{
    WebElement searchBox =  driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchBox.sendKeys(searchKeyword);
    searchBox.submit();
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

    ExpectedCondition e = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webdriver) {
            return webdriver.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchKeyword);
        }
    };

    new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(e);
}
```

and this is the test

```
@Test
public void TestThis()
{
    String searchWord = "Drupal!";
    homePage.SearchFor(searchWord);

    assertEquals("Drupal! - Google Search",homePage.GetTitle());

    homePage.CloseBrowser();
}
```

when I run this from maven (mvn clean test) i get this error

> Driver info: driver.version: unknown  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
>     at com.testTickets.app.HomePage.SearchFor(HomePage.java:36)     at
>   com.testTickets.app.TestRunner.TestThis(TestRunner.java:17)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

If i run it from the IntelliJ IDE the assert fails saying its expecting a false and getting a true.

I have been trying to debug it all day yesterday and today and can't seem to understand why this is not working. Please help

(Update: If i change the expected condition to expected conditions it starts to work

```
public void SearchFor(final String searchKeyword)
{
    WebElement searchBox =  driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchBox.sendKeys(searchKeyword);
    searchBox.submit();
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

    new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(searchKeyword));
})
```

Comment: Why do you use `toLowerCase()` method in `webdriver.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchKeyword)` snippet?

Comment: thats a fail safe. It was meant to be webdriver.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchKeyword.toLowerCase())

Comment: I have finally managed to resolve this with

     public void SearchFor(final String searchKeyword)
    {
        WebElement searchBox =  driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys(searchKeyword);
        searchBox.submit();
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

        new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(searchKeyword));
    }